# Xamarin.ios Localization with Storyboards

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, localization

Has anyone experienced issues with localization for storyboards. (I see lots of issues online people having problems with this)
I have followed the official documentation, I have tried many things from other people issues that worked for them.
I can not figure out why it does not work.

I have this in my info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>zh-Hans</string>
    </array>
```

In my Resources folder I have a `Base.lproj` that contains 
"Main.strings"
Then another folder `zh-Hans.lproj`
inside that I have Main.strings with the following content

`"196117.text" = "点击\“+ \”添加一张新卡";`
`"263697.text" = "演示卡";`
`"263698.text"= "禁用应用";`

These are labels so that is why i have the text property and the number is my Localization ID found in storyboard.

I have tried making files `Main~ipad` and `Main~iphone.strings` in the language folders.
I have tried moving the Main.storyboard into `Base.lproj` or backs into the project root.

Nothing has worked. 
Does anyone have any other advice please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have this working now, I moved my Base.Iproj out of resources with the storyboard file in Base.
Also a silly mistake I made was mixing up the i and the L. I copied the name of the file Base.lproj from Xamarin site and renamed my folder with what I copied.
I believe I might have got the name wrong, as the capital letter 'i' also looks like a lower case L as in . i = I and L =  l.

All my localization is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the directory tree looks like in my Xamarin.iOS project (localization is working fine for me):

```
MyProject.iOS
    /Resources
        /Base.lproj
            /InfoPlist.strings
        /en.lproj
            /InfoPlist.strings
        /zh-Hans.lproj
            /InfoPlist.strings
        /etc...
```

Comment: Thank you .
Mine looks similar to yours is.